# Mysql Event action stopped executing automatically

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-event

I created an event which *automatically* gets the system current date and matches it with the start and end date of a school year. If the system current date is within the start and end date of the school year, it updates the `isCurrentSchoolYear` column with `1`.

It worked perfect the first time I did this. However, when I changed the date on my PC to test if it will work with year 2020, nothing happens anymore. The `event` is set to run every **30** seconds.

**schoolyear_mt table**

(*had to manually call the* `setCurrentSchoolYear()` *stored procedure to update* `isCurrentSchoolYear` of `2020` to `1` **which is supposed to be updated automatically**)

[image]

======================================================================

`enrollmentdb.setSchoolYear` event definition:

```
CREATE EVENT enrollmentdb.e_setCurrentSchoolYear
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 second
DO CALL setCurrentSchoolYear();
```

======================================================================

```
SELECT @@event_scheduler;
```

[image]

======================================================================

```
show processlist;
```

[image]

```
show events from enrollmentdb;
```

[image]

As you can see, `Interval Value` column shows **30** but the `Time` column shows **63163099** and continues to increment.

So the problem is it doesn't **automatically** update the `isCurrentSchoolYear` column every after 30 seconds. I don't want to manually call the stored proc named  `setCurrentSchoolYear()` to make it work.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `setCurrentSchoolYear`()
BEGIN

DECLARE aSyId INT;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR sqlexception
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        RESIGNAL;
    END;

START TRANSACTION;
    -- compare the currentdate 
    SELECT schoolyear_id INTO aSyId FROM schoolyear_mt
    WHERE curdate() >= start_date AND curdate() <= end_date;

    SELECT aSyId;

    IF aSyId IS NOT NULL 
    THEN
        UPDATE schoolyear_mt SET isCurrentSchoolYear = 0 
        WHERE schoolyear_id >= 0;

        UPDATE schoolyear_mt SET isCurrentSchoolYear = 1
        WHERE schoolyear_id = aSyId;
    END IF;

COMMIT;

END
```

The problem with automatic update happened after I changed my machine's system date to **Feb 02, 2020** and also tried **Feb 02, 2015** to test if it's effective.
What could possible be hindering it from executing manually every 30 seconds?

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: I have no answer for you issue, but the method you use to update that column feels really weird. It's an easy calculation, so wouldn't it be easier to just calculate it on the fly? If you don't want to add a simple comparison to `now()` to your queries, couldn't you just make a view? Or at least run this event just once a year :)

Comment: @Nanne Yeah, actually I'm supposed to set it to every 1 year. But for testing purposes, I set it to seconds.

Comment: Every recurrent event has start time; possible something happened on server after time changing. Run `SELECT * FROM information_schema.events`, it shows more information then SHOW command. Also, try to recreate the event.

Comment: @Devart Thank you. You're right I found some conflict info. I just had to restart the services and mysql workbench. It now working. The problem occurs after system date's year is changed but after restart of XAMPP, it runs perfect.